# Android M and above storage permission issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-external-storage

my app is for takes text (String) from user and save it in internal and/or external storage, the reading from it, the issue is starting since about two dates when I tried to run the app on virtual device working with OS android 7.0.1 "Nougat" and the app skip/ignoring write to external storage permission even though I see the permission dialog square is appears when I click on external cache button

> my question is: **Is this mean There's no needed to create permission method for android OS android marshmallow and above?**

see this GIF to relate

[image]

**The whole code**

```
    public class MainFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

    private View view;
    private EditText userName2;
    private Button internalButton, externalButton, showData;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        userName2 = view.findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        internalButton = view.findViewById(R.id.internalButton);
        externalButton = view.findViewById(R.id.externalButton);
        showData = view.findViewById(R.id.showData);

        internalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveToInternalCache();
            }
        });

        externalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                enableRunTimePermisstion();


            }
        });

        showData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DataActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;

    }


    @TargetApi(23)
    public void enableRunTimePermisstion() {
        if ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) &&
                (getContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            if (getActivity().shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                (Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Write storage permission is need for app"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "request permission"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        saveToExternalCache();

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Write external storage granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                saveToExternalCache();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Write external permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            enableRunTimePermisstion();
        }
    }


    public void saveToInternalCache() {
        String userName = userName2.getText().toString();
        File path = getActivity().getCacheDir();
        File file = new File(path, "dataInternal.txt");
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOutputStream.write(userName.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data stored successfully" + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOException", e.toString());
            }
        }


    }

    public void saveToExternalCache() {
        String userName = userName2.getText().toString();
        File path = getActivity().getExternalCacheDir();
        File file = new File(path, "dataExternal.txt");
        try {
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOutputStream.write(userName.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data stored successfully"
                    + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOException", e.toString());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it depends **where** in the external storage you are writing and how you are getting the path.  Each app gets access to its own "private" external storage and external cache area, no special permission needed.  You access the path via the `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` and `Context.getExternalCacheDir()`, respectively.

If, on the other hand, you wanted to write anywhere else in external storage, such as a path acquired via a call to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, then you would need to hold the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.  Even with that there are some funky restrictions when you start working with secondary external storage.

Comment: Which the difference between Context.getExternalFilesDir(); and Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); ?

Comment: That's exactly what this answer just explained.